# Jquery Mobile overlay is turned in to page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and wanted a overlay in to be visible when ever i need. I have this at first in my html

```
<body>
   <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

(if you are wondering about other pages then they are added afterwards)
but when jquery mobile 1.4.2 initializes it turns my div in to a page like so:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a" style="min-height: 640px;">
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make Jquery not touch this element?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess you are using it to show a splash screen.

jQuery Mobile requires at least one page to exist during initialization.

To solve this problem add one dummy jQuery Mobile page and just set it CSS to **display: none;** something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div data-role="page" style="display: none;">
    <div/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems it only does it if there are no pages initially in the body. but if you add a blank page every works fine:

```
<div data-role="page"></div>
```

Comment: You were several seconds faster then me :)